# Do we need a popular videos tag or specific author tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are frequent questions based on external videos, specifically YouTube popular physics videos. For example, there are many questions based on Veritasium experiments. Would it be worth it to have a tag for [veritasium](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veritasium), [youtube](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube) or at least [popular-physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popular-physics)?

Similarly, things could be said for question about frequently used books like [griffiths-electrodynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/griffiths-electrodynamics)

Comment: I think we focus on the physics question, and not worry about the where too much. For example, we don't need a Physical Review tag.

Comment: Related question: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13917/179151

Comment: P.S. might you be suggesting that popular physics questions are ,in general, of low quality ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, these tags describe the *sources* of the questions themselves, not the *subject matter* of the question. Hence, you would not be able to tag a question with any one of those, making them **dependent** on other tags on the question. These would then be [*meta tags*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/), which are generically frowned upon.

In regards to the [popular-physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popular-physics) tag, see [this prior post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4449/25301) on the topic (and probably all the linked).