# One-way speed of light tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we make a tag for one-way speed of light questions? I saw [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/679026/can-we-measure-the-one-way-speed-of-anything-at-all) which included a link to [this search](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq%20%5Bspeed-of-light%5D%20%22one%20way%22), which combines a tag search with a text comprehension search in what seems like a pretty ugly way, that'd be much better handled by creating a proper one-way speed of light tag. It wouldn't be a meta tag, it'd simplify searching for questions on the subject, and it doesn't seem to violate the Physics SE rules, so shouldn't the community do so?

I can see that there has already been a [post on this subject](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13424/should-we-have-a-one-way-speed-of-light-tag) eight months ago, but given the lack of answers to the question (and thus the lack of consensus on the proposed solution, since there were no proposed solutions), I figured that posting a question here was probably a better course of action to kick off conversation and consensus-building than just posting an answer to that one, given my relatively low Reputation on this site.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13424/2451

Comment: Yes, I know that there was already a similar question posted. No, it doesn't resolve my question, because it does have any answers, and thus no consensus.

Comment: Related (the same cause): *[Any way to easily/automatically merge the many Veritasium questions?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13917)*

Comment: @PeterMortensen Sure, a lot of those questions are inspired by the Veritasium video, but I'm not proposing a veritasium tag, but a one-way speed of light tag.

Comment: Should we also have tags for the metric system and daylight savings time, or just one omnibus tag for questions about arbitrary conventions?

Comment: @WillO Are there questions about the metric system and daylight savings time that are related to physics? I could see a question about how the vibrations of an atom that are used to define a second is supposed to be measured, for instance, though I dunno if there have been many such questions asked. There have definitely been a number of one-way speed of light questions asked.

Comment: @nick012000 :  If there *were* a lot of questions about the metric system, would you think we should have a tag for them, or would you think it might be better not to encourage them?

Comment: @WillO "If there were a lot of questions about the metric system, would you think we should have a tag for them" Yes.

Comment: @nick012000 :  Fair enough.  I would think otherwise.

Comment: We now have a [tag:one-way-speed-of-light] tag!